# During vs. Throughout

Tags: prepositions

Physics vocabulary - Which one is the most natural?

**(a)** During the approximation process

**(b)** Throughout the approximation process

**(c)** During the approximation procedure

**(d)** Throughout the approximation procedure

**EDIT:**

More precisely: I would like to describe that a certain system property is retained 'during' the approximation process/procedure

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community See edit.

Comment: Have you checked the difference between "throughout" and "during" in the dictionaries available online? Explain your doubts.

Comment: @fev If understood correctly, the word 'throughtout' implies the idea of (temporal) regularity.  I would like to describe that the system property is retained during/throughout the mathematical procedure. I'd say that throughout is the better choice

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are hesitating and what we can provide here as a better answer than dictionaries already offer.

Comment: I encourage you to have a look at the [help centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help). You will see that questions that can be answered by dictionaries are off-topic here. DV is not mine. I find it nasty to downvote a new comer.

Comment: **throughout** need not refer to regularity.  If I say "I check my email throughout the work day" it means that I do so on multiple occasions in the morning and in the afternoon, but not necessarily with any regularity, such as every 30 minutes.  "the system property is retained" is not at all clear, so we don't know what you are trying to say.  But **throughout** can mean "for the entire time".

Comment: Per @TimR, **throughout** shows an action covers the totality of a period, not just at some point inside it. You won't go wrong with that choice.

Comment: What is "retaining" the property?

Comment: If the system property is the same before, during, and after, use *throughout*.

Comment: "During" is often used for something that pertains for a period of time but not after, as in "during a journey". "Throughout", as mentioned, implies it persists for the entire length but also persists afterwards; it also suggests more contact with the thing, while during could have a sense of "meanwhile, elsewhere". But it's not very clear from the OP exactly what nuances are required: is the property involved in the process, is it accessed once or many times, does it persist afterwards, is it meaningful afterwards...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two words have different meanings. *Throughout* means from the beginning to the end of some activity or phenomenon. *During* means only at some time or times while the activity or phenomenon is occurring, not necessarily from beginning to end.

Comment: A dictionary (eg ODE, CD) would say that 'during' can mean 'throughout' as well as 'at some time or times within [a time period]'. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/during) brings this out very clearly. Your last sentence is unclear.

Comment: Yes, of course "during" *can* mean throughout, but as I wrote it does not *necessarily* mean that. If a writer wants to be understood, they will avoid assuming that their readers take "during" to be a synonym of "throughout". For example, one could write "The audio did not work during the football game". But if "throughout" is the meaning, then "The audio did not work during the *entire* football game" is a lot clearer.

Comment: All squares are rectangles. Not all rectangles are squares. 'throughout' *specifies* that it was (a rectangle) the whole time. *during* is the 'square' and can mean either. +1. If the OP isn't going to RTM then neither should we. "The two words have different [colloquial] meanings." - *nobody* calls a square a rectangle.... but they wouldn't be wrong if they did.

Comment: 'During means only at some time or times while the activity or phenomenon is occurring' doesn't sit happily with 'During _can_ mean all the time  the activity or phenomenon is occurring'.

Comment: The word "some" does not exclude the possibility of "all".